# Api call is not working, It's giving me error that organizationId does not exist but it exist in my database, in end there is database tables and call

Tags: laravel, api

This is my api Call and under is the method I have made:

```
 Route::get('/curriculums/{curriculumId}/grades', [CurriculumController::class, 'getGradesByCurriculum']);
```

Method:

```
public function getGradesByCurriculum(Request $request)
    {
        $org = auth()->user()->organization;

        return Grade::without('curriculum')->where([
            'organizationId' => $org->id,
            'curriculumId' => $request->curriculumId,
        ])->get();
    }
```

[image][image]
[image: tables]

Comment: where is `organizationId` ? I don't see `organizationId`  in first database table picture

Comment: I think i have to get the curriculum by organizationId and then grades by curriculum, But I don't know the code for it, can you please help me?

Comment: which table is in last picture, users or oraganizations?

Comment: The curriculumId and organisationId are not in the same table, bu you are building your query like they are.  Take a look at `whereHas()`, and make sure your relationships in the model are set correctly. Apart from that I wonder why you use column names with lowerCamelCase and snake_case mixed. In Laravel you should always use snake_case for database column names.

Comment: Last picture is Curriculum table

Comment: i want to get curriculum by organization id, and grades by curriculum id

Comment: at the end i just want to return the grades

Comment: I want Select * from grades where curriculumId = ( " Id I'm providing in call  " ) join organizationId ( " i'm getting from auth user " )